# Python: Storing class type on a class variable durig class initialization

Tags: python, django, django-models, initialization

I'm trying to initialize an objects field with a class that needs to know the type that is using it:

```
class Device(Model):
    objects = AbstractManager(Device)

    # the rest of the class here
```

This is how AbstractManager is defined:

```
class AbstractManager:
    def __init__(self, cls: type):
        self.cls = cls

    def all(self):
        result = []

        for cls in self._get_subclasses():
            result.extend(list(cls.objects.all()))

        return result

    def _get_subclasses(self):
        return self.cls.__subclasses__()
```

So I can later call this and returns all() from all subclasses:

```
Device.objects.all()
```

The issue here is that I cannot use Device while initializing Device.objects, since Device is still not initialized.

As a work-around I'm initializing this outside of the class, but there's gotta be a better way:

```
class Device(Model):
    objects = None

    # the rest of the class here

Device.objects = AbstractManager(Device)
```

PD: I have a C#/C++ background, so maybe I'm thinking too much about this in a static-typing mindset, can't tell

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add any additional logic for this. Django allows you to access model class from manager using `self.model` attribute:

```
def _get_subclasses(self):
    return self.model.__subclasses__()
```

Comment: I can't do this, since Device is abstract and just adding the contribute_to_class method or inheriting Manager makes all calls to objects fail.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to do that. Django will automatically call the `contribute_to_class` method, where it will pass the model, and for a manager, it will be stored in `self.model`. You can thus simply implement this as:

```
from django.db.models.manager import ManagerDescriptor

class AbstractManager(models.Manager):

    def all(self):
        result = []

        for cls in self._get_subclasses():
            result.extend(list(cls.objects.all()))

        return result

    def contribute_to_class(self, model, name):
        self.name = self.name or name
        self.model = model
        setattr(model, name, AbstractManagerDescriptor(self))

        model._meta.add_manager(self)

    def _get_subclasses(self):
        return self.model.__subclasses__()

class AbstractManagerDescriptor(ManagerDescriptor):

    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        if instance is not None:
            raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)

        if cls._meta.swapped:
            raise AttributeError(
                "Manager isn't available; '%s.%s' has been swapped for '%s'" % (
                    cls._meta.app_label,
                    cls._meta.object_name,
                    cls._meta.swapped,
                )
            )

        return cls._meta.managers_map[self.manager.name]
```

and add the manager as:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    objects = AbstractManager()
```

That being said, I'm not sure that this is a good idea for two reasons:

1. you are returning a list, and normally `.all()` returns a `QuerySet`, you thus here "destroy" the laziness of the queryset, which can result in expensive querying; and
2. if one would use `Device.objects.filter()` for example, it would simply circumvent.

You might want to subclass the queryset, and then aim to implement that differently.

Comment: I can't do this, since Device is abstract and just adding the contribute_to_class method or inheriting Manager makes all calls to objects fail.